AWS ALB HTTPS Target Groups
I am trying to ensure that all traffic within my AWS VPC has in-transit encryption.
My architecture is currently Cloudfront -> REST API Gateway -> NLB -> ALB -> ECS Target Groups.
My idea was to make use of an Envoy sidecar to terminate TLS at the ECS container (following this). However, I am now struggling to figure out how to validate the TLS certificate that will be used for HTTPS between the ALB and the ECS container and envoy sidecar. I would prefer to use an AWS managed TLS certificate in ACM for the ALB rather than one managed by us.
Would it use the same certificate that is used by the HTTPS listener that integrates with API Gateway? Or an internal AWS certificate?


I am now struggling to figure out how to validate the TLS certificate that will be used for HTTPS between the ALB and the ECS container and envoy sidecar. I would prefer to use an AWS managed TLS certificate in ACM for the ALB rather than one managed by us.

The ALB isn't going to send a certificate at all. It is just going to use an SSL connection via the server certificate you have installed in the ECS tasks. And the ALB will not do any validation of the certificate presented to it by the server.
The certificate you associate with the ALB is only used to secure connections between the ALB, and any clients connecting to the ALB, not for the connection between the ALB and the target servers. You can also enable mTLS on an ALB, but again that is only for the connection between the ALB and clients connecting to it.
I also don't see the point of using an ALB at all in this scenario. Why not just add the ECS tasks to the NLB target group? What is the added hop through an ALB getting you?

Thanks for the insight! The intention behind the ALB is to use it to route between multiple ECS services based on the path. My thinking was that it would allow the use of a single NLB + ALB for multiple REST API Gateways. Rather than having to add the API Gateways + NLBs for every new API. Could you recommend another method for achieving something similar?

No, if you are using features like path routing you do indeed need the ALB. I was going to suggest using TCP Passthrough feature of the NLB, but unfortunately using the ALB would prevent you from using that feature.
